# How to get facebook oauth access code in spring boot?

Tags: facebook, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm setting oauth2 login (facebook) in my web application referring to some document.

> - Manual Configuration of OAuth2 Client 
>    In https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

I wrote the complete code, but it did not work. 
Below is my oauth client auth flow.
After step 4, I need to send a code and get an access token.
But I can't find the code for this anywhere.

> 1. connect - localhost:8080/login/facebook
> 2. redirect - https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=xxx&state=xxx&scope=public_profile+email+user_birthday&response_type=code&client_id=xxx&ret=login&logger_id=a10dd655-25bb-1234-baab-faeaae59d6e4&ext=1531667216&hash=Aeb1-TBSbxIpZa7c
> 3. facebook login
> 4. redirect - localhost:8008/login/facebook?code={some code}

I tried the following to get the access code using postman. But I received error messsage; Invalid verification code format (error_code 100)

> GET - https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?code=##&redirect_uri=##&client_id=##&client_secret=##

How to get access code?.. 
Why can't I get the access_code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get access code?..

OK.. there is no straight way to get access_token from *code* which is a result of `redirect - localhost:8008/login/facebook?code={some code}`

Use below API to get access_token from code.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/oauth/access_token?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&client_secret={client_secret}&code={code}
```

Result of above API would return you access_token.